Error while running BayesSearchCV for finding best hyperparameter of ANN regression
I try to apply deep learning to make regression (6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable).
Similar problems but has not been solved:
Error while running Bayesian for finding best hyperparameter
While finding solution, I got guide here: https://medium.com/latinxinai/tuning-deep-learning-made-easy-with-scikit-optimize-150c1b1d4ba
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, Nadam
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from skopt.space import Categorical

# Load dataset
dataset_path = '...'
df = pd.read_excel(dataset_path)

# Split features and target
target_col = 'Y'  # Specify the target column
X = df.drop(columns=[target_col])
y = df[target_col]

# Split data into train-test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Scale features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Callbacks
val_cb_reducelr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    factor=0.01,
    patience=10,
    verbose=1,
    min_lr=0.00001
)
val_cb_earlystop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    min_delta=0.001,
    patience=15,
    verbose=1
)
val_cb_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='checkpoints/model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.keras',
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min',
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1
)
cb_csvlogger = tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(
    filename='training_log.csv',
    separator=',',
    append=False
)

# Constants
scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
n_iter = 2
epochs = 100

# Model parameters
max_layers = 5
output_layer = Dense(1)

# Define input shape
input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],)

# Function to build search space
def build_search_space():
    search_space = {
        'lr': np.arange(0.001, 0.0501, 0.0001),
        'layers': np.arange(1, max_layers + 1),
        'batch_size': [16, 32, 64, 128],
        'optimizers': [RMSprop, Adam, Nadam]
    }
    for i in range(1, max_layers + 1):
        search_space.update({
            f'n_units{i}': np.arange(64, 513, 64),
            f'kernel{i}': ['glorot_normal', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform', 'glorot_uniform'],
            f'active{i}': ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'],
            f'dropout{i}': np.arange(0.0, 0.8, 0.1),
            f'normalizer{i}': [0, 1]
        })
    return search_space

# Function to build the model
def build_nn_model(lr, layers, batch_size, optimizers, **params):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(1, layers):
        if i == 1:
            model.add(Dense(params[f'n_units{i}'], activation=params[f'active{i}'],
                            kernel_initializer=params[f'kernel{i}'], input_shape=input_shape))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(params[f'n_units{i}'], activation=params[f'active{i}'],
                            kernel_initializer=params[f'kernel{i}']))
        model.add(Dropout(params[f'dropout{i}']))
        if params[f'normalizer{i}'] == 1:
            model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers(learning_rate=lr), loss='mae')
    return model

# Build search parameters
search_space = build_search_space()

# Wrap model for BayesSearchCV
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_nn_model, verbose=0, epochs=epochs,
                       callbacks=[val_cb_reducelr, val_cb_earlystop])

# Bayesian optimization
bayes = BayesSearchCV(estimator=model, search_spaces=search_space,
                      cv=kfold, n_iter=n_iter, scoring=scoring, verbose=1,
                      random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)

# Fit Bayesian search
bayes.fit(X_train, y_train)

But again, error occurs without solutions for it
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 463, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 291, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 598, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 136, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 876, in _fit_and_score
    estimator = estimator.set_params(**clone(parameters, safe=False))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1175, in set_params
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Invalid parameter active1 for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(active1=tanh)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 119
    114 bayes = BayesSearchCV(estimator=model, search_spaces=search_space,
    115                       cv=kfold, n_iter=n_iter, scoring=scoring, verbose=1,
    116                       random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
    118 # Fit Bayesian search
--> 119 bayes.fit(X_train, y_train)
    121 # Build tuned model
    122 tuned_model = Sequential()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py:542, in BayesSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, callback, **fit_params)
    535 if callable(self.refit):
    536     raise ValueError(
    537         "BayesSearchCV doesn't support a callable refit, "
    538         "as it doesn't define an implicit score to "
    539         "optimize"
    540     )
--> 542 super().fit(X=X, y=y, groups=groups, **fit_params)
    544 # BaseSearchCV never ranked train scores,
    545 # but apparently we used to ship this (back-compat)
    546 if self.return_train_score:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1473, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1466     estimator._validate_params()
   1468 with config_context(
   1469     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1470         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1471     )
   1472 ):
-> 1473     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:1018, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, **params)
   1012     results = self._format_results(
   1013         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
   1014     )
   1016     return results
-> 1018 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
   1020 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
   1021 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
   1022 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py:599, in BayesSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
    595 while n_iter > 0:
    596     # when n_iter < n_points points left for evaluation
    597     n_points_adjusted = min(n_iter, n_points)
--> 599     optim_result, score_name = self._step(
    600         search_space,
    601         optimizer,
    602         score_name,
    603         evaluate_candidates,
    604         n_points=n_points_adjusted,
    605     )
    606     n_iter -= n_points
    608     if eval_callbacks(callbacks, optim_result):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py:453, in BayesSearchCV._step(self, search_space, optimizer, score_name, evaluate_candidates, n_points)
    450 # make lists into dictionaries
    451 params_dict = [point_asdict(search_space, p) for p in params]
--> 453 all_results = evaluate_candidates(params_dict)
    455 # if self.scoring is a callable, we have to wait until here
    456 # to get the score name
    457 if score_name is None:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:964, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    956 if self.verbose > 0:
    957     print(
    958         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    959         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    960             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    961         )
    962     )
--> 964 out = parallel(
    965     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    966         clone(base_estimator),
    967         X,
    968         y,
    969         train=train,
    970         test=test,
    971         parameters=parameters,
    972         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    973         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    974         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    975     )
    976     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    977         enumerate(candidate_params),
    978         enumerate(cv.split(X, y, **routed_params.splitter.split)),
    979     )
    980 )
    982 if len(out) < 1:
    983     raise ValueError(
    984         "No fits were performed. "
    985         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    986         "Were there no candidates?"
    987     )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py:74, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     69 config = get_config()
     70 iterable_with_config = (
     71     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     72     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     73 )
---> 74 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:2007, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   2001 # The first item from the output is blank, but it makes the interpreter
   2002 # progress until it enters the Try/Except block of the generator and
   2003 # reaches the first `yield` statement. This starts the asynchronous
   2004 # dispatch of the tasks to the workers.
   2005 next(output)
-> 2007 return output if self.return_generator else list(output)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1650, in Parallel._get_outputs(self, iterator, pre_dispatch)
   1647     yield
   1649     with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1650         yield from self._retrieve()
   1652 except GeneratorExit:
   1653     # The generator has been garbage collected before being fully
   1654     # consumed. This aborts the remaining tasks if possible and warn
   1655     # the user if necessary.
   1656     self._exception = True

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1754, in Parallel._retrieve(self)
   1747 while self._wait_retrieval():
   1748 
   1749     # If the callback thread of a worker has signaled that its task
   1750     # triggered an exception, or if the retrieval loop has raised an
   1751     # exception (e.g. `GeneratorExit`), exit the loop and surface the
   1752     # worker traceback.
   1753     if self._aborting:
-> 1754         self._raise_error_fast()
   1755         break
   1757     # If the next job is not ready for retrieval yet, we just wait for
   1758     # async callbacks to progress.

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1789, in Parallel._raise_error_fast(self)
   1785 # If this error job exists, immediately raise the error by
   1786 # calling get_result. This job might not exists if abort has been
   1787 # called directly or if the generator is gc'ed.
   1788 if error_job is not None:
-> 1789     error_job.get_result(self.timeout)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:745, in BatchCompletionCallBack.get_result(self, timeout)
    739 backend = self.parallel._backend
    741 if backend.supports_retrieve_callback:
    742     # We assume that the result has already been retrieved by the
    743     # callback thread, and is stored internally. It's just waiting to
    744     # be returned.
--> 745     return self._return_or_raise()
    747 # For other backends, the main thread needs to run the retrieval step.
    748 try:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:763, in BatchCompletionCallBack._return_or_raise(self)
    761 try:
    762     if self.status == TASK_ERROR:
--> 763         raise self._result
    764     return self._result
    765 finally:

ValueError: Invalid parameter active1 for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(active1=tanh)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

How to solve it?

Maybe the hyperparameter names need a prefix?  https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/advanced.html#routed-parameters

@Ben Reiniger Would you please tell me more details ?
